# Using @XmlAnyElement in Java marshalling

Tags: java, jaxb, jax-ws, cxf

I have this class

```
public class Header {

    @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
    protected List<Object> any;

    // getters/setters omitted

}
```

How can I (in JAX-WS WebMethod) create an element ID in header that would look like this?

```
<Header>
    <ID>value</ID>
</Header>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could have a class like the following and add an instance of it into the `any` property, or you could add an instance of `org.w3c.dom.Element` representing the `ID` element to the collection.

```
@XmlRootElement(name="ID")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ID {

    @XmlValue
    private String value;

}
```

Comment: It might be worth adding `@XmlSeeAlso(ID.class)` to the `Header` class too, so as to guarantee that JAXB notices it.